# Selecting rows on basis of the string length of two columns

Tags: r, select, dataframe, row

I want to select the rows of a data frame in which the length of the string in the column v3 is equal to the length of the string of the column v4.
My dataframe 'df' looks like:

```
    v1  v2  v3  v4
1   456 .   C   T
2   462 .   C   T
3   497 .   C   T
4   499 .   GC  AC
5   499 .   GC  G
6   499 .   GC  CC
7   513 .   GCACA   GCA
8   513 .   GCACA   GCACACA
9   513 .   GCACA   ACACA
10  513 .   GCACA   GCACACACA
11  513 .   GCACA   GCACACACACA

12  513 .   GCACA   GACCACA
13  513 .   GCACA   G
14  521 .   ACN A
15  522 .   CNN C
```

The output should be:

```
v1  v2  v3  v4
1   456 .   C   T
2   462 .   C   T
3   497 .   C   T
4   499 .   GC  AC
9   513 .   GCACA   ACACA
```

I have tried:
 `new_df = df[nchar(str_sub(df$v3))==nchar(str_sub(df$v4))]`

Comment: You are close , just add a comma to select rows. `df[nchar(str_sub(df$v3))==nchar(str_sub(df$v4)),]`

Answer (score 7):

@agstudy got the most important part. I would add that `str_sub` (from the `stringr` package I assume) is not doing anything useful here. Last, you could use `subset` to avoid the repetitive use of `df$`. So you can do:

```
df[nchar(df$v3) == nchar(df$v4), ]
```

or

```
subset(df, nchar(v3) == nchar(v4))
```

Comment: @user3184877: If this answered your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the tick mark on the left, thank you.