# R: how to subset data with condition of taking out only rows with one character in a column

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am wondering how to take out a subset of a dataframe based on the whether a column has  a one character or more than one character.

```
dt = data.frame(id = c(1,2,3),character = c("a", "a a", "b"), stringsAsFactors = F)
#           id                 character
#1          1                  a
#2          2                  a a
#3          3                  b
```

what i want to get is the only those rows with only one character in the character column, namely:

```
  #           id                 character
  #1          1                  a
  #3          3                  b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a variation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068662/selecting-rows-on-basis-of-the-string-length-of-two-columns-in-r) solution.

Adapted to your question, dataframe subsetting can be used in the following:

```
subsetDF <- dt[nchar(dt$character)==1, ]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `nchar` to find the number of characters, check if it is equal to 1 (`==1`) and use that to `subset` the rows of the dataset.

```
subset(dt, nchar(as.character(character))==1)
#  id character
#1  1         a
#3  3         b
```

---

Or we use `grep`

```
dt[grep("^\\S$", dt$character),]
```